# After migration from MOSS 2007 TO SHAREPOINT 2010 broken pics

Tags: permissions, migration

I've migrated my MOSS 2007 portal to sharepoint 2010 and i had no customization in my previous portal and it was totally out of the box. Migration was successful although facing the following problems.

1. I had couple of static pics (our product advertisements) in my previous portal but when i access the page in sharepoint 2010 as farm administrator I could see the pics but when visitors visit the page they get "X" mark (broken pics) ...
2. some of the pages has list and when user hit the list they get access denied...although in my previous portal it was working fine...

How to resolve both issues...additionally plz guide how to reset permissions and create permissions from scratch...

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If users have access to the site, but not to specific lists, that means that those lists have broken inheritance and have specific permissions that are different from their parent. If you want those lists to have the same permissions as the site, then set those lists to inherit permissions again. Here are the steps to do that:

1. Open the list (For your images, look at the url to see what library those files are in)
2. From the ribbon, click **List Settings** or **Document Library Settings**
3. Click **Permissions for this list** or **Permissions for this document library**
4. From the ribbon, click **Inherit Permissions**

Answer (score 2):

This could either be a permission issue (as laurie mention) but it could also be, that the images isnt published. Find the images in the library where they reside and check if the list has publishing enabled. Then check if the pictures in question is checked in and published -and hence have a major version

Comment: Problem is that i have one person JOSH who is site collection administrator...when he visits the page the images appear..but being end user or even i myself added in site collection administrator as secondary resource but i cant see images..it appears broken...i am confused about the permission...dont know how to grant permissions and where to start...webapplication->sitecollection->site->user???

Comment: That behaviour is consistent with both unpublished items and permission issue. Inspect the URL of the offending images to identify in what library the images are located. You cannot do anything about this without proper permissions, so i suggest you and your administrator sit down together and locate where the images reside, then see if you have either unpublished items or if inheritance has been broken. I recommend using MCS (Site Actions > Manage Content and Structure) if the issue is publishing, since you can pull out lists of unpublished items, items checked out by me etc